# Where to look at the highest cpu usage in linux

Tags: linux, process, cpu

I know about `VmHWM` usage in linux in `/proc/[pid]/status` where I can look at high water mark. Is there something similar for cpu usage? I mean `top -p [pid]` shows the current cpu usage. But I would like to know about the highest... Is there something for that in linux

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Highest cpu usage shouldn't be always 100% ???

Answer (score 1):

You can use `top -o cpu -n 1  | grep 'PID' -A1`.

The command does the following:

- `top -o cpu` returns sorts by cpu usage
- `-n 1` shows only the first line
- `grep 'PID' -A1` greps for PID and returns the following line

This will give you a constantly updating output of two lines. The first one are the labels and the second one the process.

Depending on what you want to use it for you can do some string processing with `awk` or `sed`